# Как в button к атрибуту name добавить 2 значения и передать один из них в PHP форму?

Tags: php

Код вот такой :

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="do_login stillblock"> Войти</button>
```

do_login  отвечает за регистрацию, а 
stillblock отвечает за то, чтобы блок оставался на месте, но я не могу из использовать одновременно

Comment: 'stillblock отвечает за то, чтобы блок оставался на месте' можно по подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: В общем у меня две формы регистрации, одна постоянная на сайте, а вторая появляется при нажатии, в общем, процесс регистрации одинаковый(нажимаю на кнопку и происходит регистрация). Но только вот вторая форма появляется поверх всех элементов, и когда я нажимаю на кнопку "вход" эта форма приобретает display:none;, а я хочу чтобы при нажатии на "вход" эта форма оставалось на месте, а процесс регистрации на двух формах был одинаковый

Comment: извините но я все равно не понял зачем вам два параметра в name, можете дать ссылку на сайт?

Comment: Он локальный, а можно ли класс передать в PHP ? И вообще можно ли сделать два параметра в name ?

Comment: вы скорей всего подходите к проблеме не с той стороны, в принципе не должна возникать ситуация когда вам нужно передать 2 значение в name. Можете предоставить немного больше кода, может тогда буде понятней

Comment: Скорее всего, попробую еще раз объяснить,ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО форма регистрации имеет display NONE. 
Есть кнопка назовем ее "SHOW" , когда я на нее нажимаю форма "регистрация" приобретает display BLOCK, и почему-то когда я нажимаю любую кнопку в этой форме,  она опять прячется, то есть приобретает display:none.
Коротко говоря, как сделать так, чтобы форма регистрации при нажатии на SHOW всегда имела DISPLAY BLOCK

Comment: при чём здесь тогда вообще php и name , если здесь дело в js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нельзя задавать несколько названий для поля**.
Атрибут name должен содержать одно название поля. В Вашем случае название поля - "do_login stillblock".

Вы можете передать скрытое поле в форме, если собираетесь использовать это в PHP.

```
<input name="stillblock" type="hidden" value="true">
```

Вы можете задавать свойства через атрибут `data-*`, если собираетесь обрабатывать поле в JS, jQuery или иных фреймворках.

```
<button class="btn" id="register" type="submit" name="do_login" data-stillblock="true"> Войти</button>
```

Тогда в обработке (пример jQuery):

```
$('#register').on('click', function(){ // Кликнули на кнопку
   if($(this).data('stilblock') !== false){ //Если атрибут "data-stillblock" хоть чем-то заполнен
       //Ваши действия
       return false; //Блокировка отправки формы (если требуется)
   }
});
```

Comment: Класс, а это работает, спасибо бальшое